# How to get "extended" path info from URL in a plugin

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, query-string

Working on a plugin that creates short codes to embed into a page.

I have permalinks set to "Post name", so http://example.com/post-name/

I want to be able to pass additional information in the URL so the short code can use it, for example:
http://example.com/foo-page/bar-thing/
as opposed to ?name=value

On our dev servers, this works and I can do something like the following to get the value:

```
$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$page_id = $post->post_name;
$thing_pos = strpos( $url, "/" . $page_id );
$thing = substr( $url, $pos + strlen( $page_id ) + 2 );
```

$thing now equals "bar-thing";

On some servers, however, I get a "That page can’t be found" message. (the page id is correct)  I have compared the settings and I can't find any differences in permalinks settings, etc.

All the servers are running 5.1.1

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've searched for a couple of hours and I can't locate any info about this - I'm probably not using the correct search terms.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

I've added the following code to my plugin php:

```
function custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%myid%',
        '([^/]+)'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^category/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=mypage&myid=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

And I'm still getting a 404 when I go to "mypage" with anything following the pagename, like so: http://example.com/mypage/foo.  http://example.com/mypage works fine and the plugin loads and executes.

**Update 2**

Been working on this all day, still can't get it to work.  The current code:

In functions.php

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars', 10, 1);
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "test"; 
    return $vars;
}
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^category/([0-9]+)/?', 'category?test=$1', 'top');
}
```

In the plugin:

```
$test = get_query_var( 'test' );
```

When I go to this a URL like this: http://example.com/category?test=123 I get 123 in $test as expected.  When I go to http://example.com/category/123 I get an error 404.  I have updated the permalinks in wp-admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reply to "**Update 1**":

The code worked fine for me. So,

> I'm still getting a 404 when I go to "mypage" with anything following
>   the pagename, like so: http://example.com/mypage/foo.

Because your RegEx pattern is `^category/([^/]+)/?`, so the URL you should have visited is `http://example.com/category/foo`. But then, you shouldn't use `category` because that "base" is used for category archive permalinks — unless of course you changed it to something like `topics`.

So you'd use `^mypage/([^/]+)/?` and not `^category/([^/]+)/?`.

However, you should know that the rewrite rule would conflict with pages which are children of the `mypage` page. I.e. If `foo` is a child of `mypage`, then `mypage/foo` would load the `mypage` page and not the child `foo` page.

In reply to "**Update 2**":

> When I go to http://example.com/category/123 I get an error 404.

Because WordPress treats the request/URL as a category archive request, so WordPress tries to load a category with the slug of `123` and when not found, the error `404` is thrown. But the `$test` (i.e. `get_query_var( 'test' )`) would actually give you the expected value which is `123` as in the above example URL. :)

Comment: I feel so stupid - I completely overlooked the fact that category is a reserved name in WordPress.

Comment: Yes, it's reserved. But it can be changed via the Permalink Settings page - see "Category base" at the bottom of the page.